# Berry curvature vanishes in TRS system

Tags: condensed-matter, curvature, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In spin 1/2 system with TR symmetry , the Berry curvature must vanish. Because Berry curvature is odd. How to prove it?
\begin{equation}
\langle\partial_{-k_x}u^{I}(-k)|\partial_{-k_y}u^{I}(-k)\rangle-x\leftrightarrow y=-\langle\partial_{k_x}u^{II}(k)|\partial_{k_y}u^{II}(k)\rangle-x\leftrightarrow y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\langle\partial_{-k_x}u^{II}(-k)|\partial_{-k_y}u^{II}(-k)\rangle-x\leftrightarrow y=-\langle\partial_{k_x}u^{I}(k)|\partial_{k_y}u^{I}(k)\rangle-x\leftrightarrow y
\end{equation}
The equation above means $F(-k_x,-k_y)=-F(k_x,k_y) $
How do we prove the above equation ?

Comment: See answer already given here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422788/relation-between-topological-insulators-and-breaking-of-time-reversal-symmetry/480983#480983

Comment: No, this is a different argument: the presence of time-reversal symmetry is enough to make the Chern number/relative index vanish, but it does not imply that the Berry curvature vanishes. In fact, the statement in the title is false: the presence of time-reversal symmetry makes Berry curvature an odd function. It does *not* imply that it vanishes pointwise. You need e. g. inversion symmetry in combination with TRS: the presence of inversion symmetry implies $F(-k) = + F(+k)$ and the only function that is odd and even at the same time is $F(k) = 0$.